# Добавление цикла в combobox с функцией JS

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

В одной из прошлых тем я получил решение для combobox, при нажатии на любой элемент из списка которого - происходил переход по ссылке.

```
// JS
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select[name=select]').change(function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {    
                    window.location = $(this).val();
            }
    });
});
</script>

// PHP
echo "<select name=\"select\">";
echo "<option value=\"http://ya.ru/\">123</option>";
echo "<option value=\"http://ya.ru/\">456</option>";
echo "</select>"
```

Собственно в такой связке работает, все супер, но возникла проблемка. Если выводить <option> циклом, то первое значение удивительным образом не работает

```
// PHP
$massiv_test[] = "123";
$massiv_test[] = 3;
$massiv_test[] = 4;
$massiv_test[] = 5;
$massiv_test[] = 6;
$massiv_countx = count($massiv_test);

echo "<select name=\"select\">";
while ($num_mas < $massiv_countx)
{
    $num_mas = $num_mas + 1;
    echo "<option value=\"http://ya.ru/\">456</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Ну и вопрос прост, почему так?

P.s. Если скопировать код с выведенной страницы и вставить в место цикла - работает.

Comment: Вы 5 раз выводите <option value=\"http://ya.ru/\">456</option> ?
Зачем тогда вообще массив $massiv_test ? Это точно правильный кусок кода ?

Comment: валуе у меня value=\"http://ya.ru/\" . код точно правильный. вот сижу гадаю, почему не получастся. кстати, если нажать на любой пункт кроме первого, потом в браузере назад, и потом нажать первый - работает 8-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скопироваль ваш код. Все прекрасно работает....

Answer (score 0):

хм.. сильно не вчитывался, но сразу вижу что переменная $num_mas у вас не определенна.
$num_mas = $num_mas + 1; 
лучше заменить на $num_mas++

Comment: "$num_mas + 1; лучше заменить на $num_mas++" кроме читабельности - чем?